# ¿Cómo hacer consultas SUM y GROUP BY en firebase firestore o como evitar retornar gran cantidad de datos?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Tengo la siguiente coleccion en firestore:

```
Transacciones
           |_ JS78A58mA5M(id documento)
                       |_TipoMovimiento(string)
                       |_Area(string)
                       |_Fecha(timestamp)
                       |_Valor(number)
                       |_Year(number)
                       |_FechaCrea(timestamp)
                       |_UsuarioCrea(string)
                       |_FechaActualiza(string)
                       |_UsuarioActualiza(string)
```

Ahora bien, quiero hacer un gráfico que muestre mes a mes tanto los ingresos como las salidas y un total actual (la resta entre entradas y salidas), además de otras graficas, como la cantidad de entradas por cada area, la cantidad de salidas por cada area y así, entonces en SQL yo lo haría haciendo la siguiente consulta

```sql
SELECT MONTH(Fecha) AS 'Mes', TipoMovimiento, Area, SUM(Valor) AS 'Valor'
FROM Transacciones
Where Year = '2020'
GROUP BY MONTH(Fecha), TipoMovimiento, Area
ORDER BY MONTH(Fecha), TipoMovimiento, Area ASC
```

Para así poder generar los gráficos con sus movimientos mensuales, ya con estos datos, en el front ya hago los respectivos recorridos para agrupar por areas y hacer las sumas y demás.

El tema es que podria hacer la consulta para firebase así tal cual

```js
db.collection("transacciones").where("Year", "==", this.model.year).orderBy("FechaCrea", "asc").orderBy("TipoMovimiento", "asc").orderBy("Area", "asc")
```

y traerme todos los documentos de la colleccion de `transacciones` pero tambien sé que la cuota de transferencia sería más alta, ya que técnicamente estoy haciendo un select así más o menos:

```sql
SELECT MONTH(Fecha) AS 'Mes', TipoMovimiento, Area, Valor
FROM Transacciones
Where Year = '2020'
ORDER BY MONTH(Fecha), TipoMovimiento, Area
```

y por ejemplo, en lugar de traerme 60 registros, me puede traer unos 200 o más.

Ya entendiendo esto, ¿cómo hago esa consulta en firebase, de qué manera puedo agrupar mi consulta o cual sería la manera más óptima de traer mis datos de firebase sin sacrificar cuota de transferencia?

El front que uso es Vue js, valga la aclaración

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

No existe el groupBy en Firebase ni nada similar. Es una base de datos no relacional y si ese dato es importante para vos te conviene tenerlo precalculado y guardarlo aparte.
Se que en Bases de datos tradicionales tener datos calculados es antinatural pero en el mundo no relacional es algo bastante mas necesario, ya que se prioriza hacer lecturas rapidas y se mantiene la integridad de los datos con triggers.

En este caso puntual te recomendaria armar una tabla de Movimientos por Mes, donde tengas los totaliadores que necesites e ir modificandolos cada vez que se agregue un nuevo documento en transacciones.

En general siempre intenta que exista una tabla que tenga los datos listos para ser mostrados tal y como los vas a mostrar

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias